# Adding new lines between two strings with regex

Tags: python, regex

In a document, every time the pattern

```
$$mystring$$
```

occurs on a single line, I need new lines to be added between the $$s and the string i.e.:

```
$$
mystring
$$
```

Here is my attempt

```
s = "$$mystring1$$ \n $$mystring2$$ \n $$fake"

print(re.sub('\n\$\$.*?\$\$',"\n\\1\n",s))
```

Should produce:

```
$$
mystring1
$$
$$
mystring2
$$
$$fake
```

Comment: try [`re.sub(r'(?<=\$\$)(.*?)(?=\$\$)', r"\n\1\n", s)`](https://akuiper.com/console/C8Ju58hR3N7w)

Comment: The phrase "occurs on a single line" is ambiguous. Please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your `$$...$$` pattern must occupy the whole line (with or without leading/trailing whitespaces).

In this case, you do not need a regex, you can use

```py
s = "$$mystring1$$ \n $$mystring2$$ \n $$fake"
output = []
for l in s.splitlines():
    l = l.strip()
    if l.startswith('$$') and l.endswith('$$'):
        output.append('$$\n' + l[2:-2] + '\n$$')
    else:
        output.append(l.strip())

print('\n'.join(output))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/tX75Kx). That is, if a line starts and ends with `$$`, get the line part without the first and last two chars and wrap it with newlines, else, just keep the line as is.

Output:

```
$$
mystring1
$$
$$
mystring2
$$
$$fake
```

If you need to break the lines at doubled `$$`s, you can use something like

```py
import re
s = "$$mystring1$$ \n $$mystring2$$ \n $$fake"
print(re.sub(r'(\$\$)(.*?)(\$\$)', '\\1\n\\2\n\\3', s))
```

See [this Python demo](https://ideone.com/quVeJj). Output:

```
$$
mystring1
$$ 
 $$
mystring2
$$ 
 $$fake
```

The `(\$\$)(.*?)(\$\$)` matches `$$` and captures it into Group 1, then captures into Group 2 any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible, and then captures into Group 3 a `$$` substring. The replacement pattern just keeps these groups inserting line feeds between Group 1 and 2 and Group 2 and 3.

Answer (score 1):

The pattern `\n\$\$.*?\$\$` starts the match with a newline, directly followed by `$$`

That pattern does not match in `$$mystring1$$ \n $$mystring2$$ \n $$fake`

---

Another option could be using 2 capture groups, matching what you don't want and capturing what you want to keep.

In the callback check for the existence of the groups for the replacement.

```
^\s*(?:\$\$(.*?)\$\$\s*|(\$\$.*))$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `\s*` Match optional whitspace chars
- `(?:` Non capture group for the alternation

  - `\$\$(.*?)\$\$\s*` Capture any char in between 2 dollar signs in **group 1**
  - `|` Or
  - `(\$\$.*)` capture 2 dollar signs and the rest of the string in **group 2**
- `)` Close non capture group
- `$` End of string

See s [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/jUmbqL/1/) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/UcU00C)

```
import re

pattern = r"^\s*(?:\$\$(.*?)\$\$\s*|(\$\$.*))$"
s = "$$mystring1$$ \n $$mystring2$$ \n $$fake"

result = re.sub(
    pattern,
    lambda x: x.group(2) if x.group(2) else f"$$\n{x.group(1)}\n$$",
    s,
    0,
    re.MULTILINE
)

print(result)
```

Output

```
$$
mystring1
$$
$$
mystring2
$$
$$fake
```